# Reading Time HH:mm:ss from excel cell in c#

Tags: c#

I need to extract the time from an excel file. The time in excel is expressed in hours:minutes:seconds. The c# code i have that reads the time is:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString());   
string GetTime = String.Format("{0:t}", dt);
```

This code works perfect with one file but when i insert another similar file it does not reads the time. Does anyone know why this happens.

Excel table that DOES read the time:

| Id | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18/11/2022 | 11:51:00 |

Excel table that DOES NOT read the time:

| Id | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08/08/2022 | 06:54:00 |

Comment: Don't use `Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString())` to begin with. Excel supports dates and any Excel library should read the date value as a DateTime. If the value is a DateTime, you're only wasting RAM. Cast the value to a DateTime and read the time with the [TimeOfDay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday?view=net-7.0) property., eg `((DateTime)worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value).TimeOfDay

Comment: Doesn't read time how? Throws exception?

Comment: in the output window i read "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution you have to use `FromOADate` to get the correct format.
`DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate((double)worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value);`

Answer (score 3):

Excel supports dates natively. Dates are stored in binary form (specifically a floating point number), not as text. They have no format. How they're displayed depends on the cell's numeric format and the end user's locale settings, but the actual value remains binary.

Even when you see a time text in a field, the underlying value is a `DateTime` whose numeric style shows only the time part. You can test that by changing the cell's numeric style to a full date time or number.

All Excel libraries will load Excel dates as .NET DateTime values. If the Excel sheet contains actual dates, `Value` is already a DateTime. To get its time part use the [DateTime.TimeOfDay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday?view=net-7.0) property.

For example :

```
TimeSpan time = ((DateTime)worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value).TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: But it still does not read the time from second table. It doesn't cast the value to DateTime even if time is 06:54:00

Comment: _How_ does it not "read the time"? Does it throw an exception? Wrong Value? No Value? ...

Comment: @Valkyrie parsing time alone makes no sense, there is no "Time" data type. Consider adding the two values (date part + time part; the whole/integer part is the date, decimal part is the time: day=1, hour=1/24) before reading them into a `DateTime`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you can't add two `DateTime` values. Excel stores both dates and times as an OADate. The time values have a date part equal to `0001-01-01`. These values are displayed as time of day simply because the numeric style is set to that.

Comment: I know that. I'm saying if you add the two cells _in Excel_ and read the cell with the sum you'll get a DateTime with the correct date and the correct time.

Comment: @Fildor it doesn't throw any error in error list. It doesn't stop my program but in the output window i read "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException"